# printf isn't working why?

Tags: c

No compiler error but I'm not seeing the statement from printf (after the loop). The printf before the loop is all good. I couldn't figure out to solve this problem.

```
   int prime(int n); 


    int main(void)
    {
        int num = 0; 
        bool prime; 
        int n; 
        int count; 
        int sum; 

        printf("Enter the limit:", n); 
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Primes up to %d\n", n); 


        // loop 
        for(int i =2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            prime = true; 
            for(int j =2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if(i%j == 0)
                {
                    prime = false;
                    break; 
                }
            }
            if(prime)
            {
                num += i; 
                printf("%d ", i);

            }
        }
        return num;
        count++;
        sum += count; 
        // sum of primes

        printf("Number of primes: \n", sum);
    }
```

Why is that?

Comment: `return num;`: this line terminates function execution. Nothing after it is going to be executed.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`)? Your compiler should have told you something about the `printf` calls and uninitialized variables. And what's that `int prime(int n);` all about? Also, this doesn't look like C++.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and let your compiler help you with that.

Answer (score 5):

Because you `return num` before it, that means it ends your function before. It should work if you change the end of your function to this:

```
count++;
sum += count; 
// sum of primes

printf("Number of primes: \n", sum);
return num;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.